# How to transform T4 template with TextTransform

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, t4, xbuild

How do I transform T4 templates using the `TextTransform.exe` utility available in monodevelop for linux?

```
$ /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/TextTransform.exe Foo.tt
```

By calling directly `TextTransform.exe` with a valid template file, it generates an empty cs file. Instead, if I use MonoDevelop, I select the template file and I use the tool "Process T4 template", everything works fine.

I also had a look at the possible options of `TextTransform.exe`, but I cannot figure out how to use them.

The reason because I want to generate the cs files from the templates, is that I need to build my application on a build server. It would be nice if `xbuild` could that as a pre-build target automatically, but that's not the case. My idea is now to define a new target and call it before I build the application.

Comment: What does your T4 file look like?

Comment: that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737306/running-texttransform-exe-t4-on-a-build-server