# Run TextTransform.exe with args from Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, t4

I want to run TextTransform.exe with the parameter args on my template while in PowerShell v3. Here are my variables and the options I tried.  Note that it works with no '-a' parameters, but I need the args to run the template correctly.

```
$textTransformPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\14.0\TextTransform.exe"
$templateath = "$ProjectPath\TheTemplate.tt"
$textTransformParams = "-a !!TheParam!$TheValue"

#& "$textTransformPath" "$templatePath" <-- this runs, but no args!

# these don't work:
& "$textTransformPath" "$templatePath" $textTransformParams
& "$textTransformPath" "$templatePath" "$textTransformParams"
```

I don't know why this is so difficult, it seems like it should be really easy.  If I type out this in the standard command line it works, which verifies the problem is with my PS syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never fails...one last search after almost giving up and found the answer:

[Using $(SolutionDir) when running template via TextTransform.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805563/using-solutiondir-when-running-template-via-texttransform-exe)

The combo I apparently didn't try previously was:

```
& "$textTransformPath" "$templatePath" -a !!TheParam!$TheValue
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: 6 years later, thanks for the help!