# How do I define an assembly directive path relative to the template file in a T4 template?

Tags: c#, t4

I have a T4 template file that is included in many other T4 templates in different projects and solutions that are on different depth levels of the file system. In the assembly directive I can't use Macros like $(ProjectDir) or $(SolutionDir). I need to use a path relative to the T4 file itself.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can create a T4 that probes the absolute paths of the asemblies and that generates another T4 with these paths in the assembly directives.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to elaborate because `$(SolutionDir)` works just fine like the following code:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)MyFile.dll"#>
```

It doesn't work from TextTransform.exe though. There are [workarounds for TextTransform.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805563/using-solutiondir-when-running-template-via-texttransform-exe) though with PowerShell.